# Not able to understand Kafka Connect in distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am started Kafka connect in stand alone mode like below

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
```

After that i have created a connector with all details using rest API .
Like this

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","tasks.max":"5","topics":"fsp-AUDIT_EVENT_DEMO","key.ignore":"true","connection.url":"https://**.amazonaws.com","type.name":"kafka-connect-distributed","name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","errors.tolerance":"all","errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"fsp-dlq-audit-event"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq
```

After that when i check status i can see 5 task running

```
curl  localhost:8083/connectors/elastic-search-sink-audit/tasks | jq
```

**Question 1:**

Does this mean i am running my kafka connect connecter in distributed mode or in Standalone mode only ?

**Question 2:**

Do i have to modify connect-distributed.properties file and start like stand alone ?

**Question 3:**

Currently i am running all my set up in only one EC2 ,Now if i have to add 5 more EC2 to make connector more parallel and speed up how can i make this How will kafka connect understand 5 more EC2 has been added and it has to share workload ?

**Question 4:**
Do i have to run and start and create kafka connect in all ec2 and just start ? How can i confirm that all 5 EC2 are running properly with same connector .

Last i have given try starting connector in distributed mode .
First i started like this

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-distributed /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
```

and then in another session using rest API i submitted like this

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","tasks.max":"5","topics":"fsp-AUDIT_EVENT_DEMO","key.ignore":"true","connection.url":"https://**.amazonaws.com","type.name":"kafka-connect-distributed","name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","errors.tolerance":"all","errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"fsp-dlq-audit-event"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq
```

But as soon as hit this i started getting error like this

```
rror: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
[2020-02-01 13:48:15,551] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 159 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483496 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
[2020-02-01 13:48:15,652] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 160 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483495 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
[2020-02-01 13:48:15,753] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 161 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483494 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
[2020-02-01 13:48:15,854] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 162 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483493 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
[2020-02-01 13:48:15,956] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 163 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147483492 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
```

Finally request time out when i try to create connector using curl

```
{ "error_code": 500, "message": "Request timed out" }
```

Please help me understand this .

Comment: By the way, you might want to look at using Landoop Kafka Connect UI

Comment: @cricket_007  Yes that is good but i am running on EC2 Linux in aws where i do not have enough permission ...Landdop can i can see my local but not in EC2 AWS

Comment: Permissions to do what? You apparently are able to download Kafka, so why not anything else? EC2 doesn't matter and you can run the UI on your own machine

Comment: @cricket_007 i do not have connectivity of EC2 from my local machine ..I am doing everything in AWS .So basically i can not ping or telnet from my local to EC2

Comment: How are you using ssh then? That's just a VPC configuration... Or you can SSH tunnel any HTTP port

Comment: @cricket_007 i am doing ssh using Bastion host tunnel on port yes

Answer (score 3):

Both modes start a REST API

Distributed mode does not accept a properties file for the connectors, you must POST it. There is no reason to do that in standalone as the connectors that you provide from the command line are already running

Distributed mode is recommended because the state of the connectors is stored back into a Kafka topic rather than maintained in files on the single machine running standalone mode

For more details, please refer - [Kafka Connect Concepts](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html)

> How will kafka connect understand 5 more EC2 has been added and it has to share workload ?
>
> Do i have to run and start and create kafka connect in all ec2 and just start ? How can i confirm that all 5 EC2 are running properly with same connector.

Well, your EC2 machines don't know to start any process unless they're part of some distributed cluster, so you must start distributed mode on each, using the same settings (Confluent's Ansible repo makes this really easy).

You can hit the /status endpoint of any Connect server to see which addresses are running which tasks

> NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS

Because you don't have enough brokers to create the internal Kafka Connect topics for tracking state

Comment: Which means my distributed mode has not started .Can you please suggest something at my last part of the question ..

Comment: Make sure you have at least three healthy kafka brokers

Comment: I have 2 broker per 3 avalability zone so total 6 brokers

Comment: Also do i have run like also and then curl `/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-distributed /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties`? Or just curl

Comment: Again, distributed mode does not take properties files for any connectors. You must curl a json payload

Comment: If you have 6 brokers, then the default replicas of 3 should not be complaining about there not being enough...

Comment: Ok then if i run only using curl then i get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8083: Connection refused
` error ... Which means i have to start something ..If i do not start connecter using properties file then for every rest api i get same error ..Connection refused

Comment: It's just `connect-distributed /path/to/connect-distributed.properties`. And like I mentioned, Ansible scripts make that easy to do for a cluster of any size

Comment: Even with also i get same error ..`/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-distributed /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` .Ansible is new to me ..I will definetly have a look into this ..Thanks for suggesting that ..But for now i am not able to start in distributed mode .Atleast in single EC2 only i am trying

Comment: What's the error? Not enough replicas? That script doesn't run any curl commands

Comment: Are you able to create the topics yourself? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode

Comment: So i first run `/bin/connect-distributed /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties` which has distributed properties and then ran curl command in another session `curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","config":{"connector.class":"*.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","tasks.max":"5","topics":"fsp_DEMO","key.ignore":"true","connection.url":"https://***.*.com","type.name":"kafka-connect-distributed","name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","errors.tolerance":"all","errors.deadletterqueu.topic.name":"faudit-event"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq`

Comment: yes all topic is created automatically  when i list then i can see

Comment: That's correct... Still not clear what your error is

Comment: In last part of question i get same error .`[2020-02-01 14:36:04,129] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 947 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147482707 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)` .But i should run properties first and then curl ? Is that correct ?

Comment: That's just a warning. If you can describe the topics and they all look healthy (all have 3 ISR), you can ignore that. But yes start the REST API before you curl it... And if you install Confluent Platform using YUM/APT like I think I told you before, you should be using `systemctl` commands to start Kafka Connect in distributed mode as a background process

Comment: Just one reqest can you please elaborate little more may be in answer 1. How to start rest API before curl ? I just hit curl command .2 How to start connect in distributed mode using `systemctl` ..And i have not installed kafka connect using YUM/APT its just download and then i started using in standalone mode .

Comment: 1) connect-distributed starts a Connect worker. The worker starts its own HTTP server with a REST API. You cannot curl something that's not running any HTTP server 2) Search the Confluent documentation on installing the platform using YUM/APT rather than extracting the tar.gz files

Comment: agreed ..I started rest server as well like `/usr/local/confluent/bin/kafka-rest-start /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties` and then distributed propeties and then curl ...But after curl again same error  and in curl window `{
  "error_code": 500,
  "message": "Request timed out"
}
`

Comment: No. Kafka Connect has nothing to do with the REST Proxy. They don't even communicate with each other. You're mixing up my words

Comment: i am confused now ..I dont know why i am getting Request time put error ..

Comment: I'm not really sure. Sounds like a networking problem or your Connect server is being stopped when you disconnect from ssh

Comment: i am able to start in standalone mode ...When i ssh i start all first

Comment: Also, talk to this guy https://stackoverflow.com/q/60023497/2308683