# Request timed out Message while starting Kafka connect in distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have downloaded confluent version 5.4 .

**And i have connector running good in stand alone mode .**

```
wget /usr/local http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.4/confluent-5.4.0-2.11.tar.gz -P ~/Downloads/
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/confluent-5.4.0-2.11.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/
sudo mv ~/Downloads/confluent-5.4.0 /usr/local/
```

and then i am trying to run Kafak connect on distributed mode so i modified my connect-distributed.properties like below

```
bootstrap.servers=b-***.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-***.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-***.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/usr/local/confluent/share/java
```

and then i start my connector like below

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-distributed /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

it looks like it started successfully [2020-02-02 05:22:33,860] INFO Joined group and got assignment:

```
Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-c99d50a9-faf0-4b15-8a3d-3add55b7e206', leaderUrl='http://10.97.49.217:8083/', offset=-1, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1216)
[2020-02-02 05:22:33,861] INFO Starting connectors and tasks using config offset -1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:850)
[2020-02-02 05:22:33,861] INFO Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:860)
```

Finally i am using curl command to create my sink connector .

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","tasks.max":"2","topics":"fsp-AUDIT_EVENT_DEMO","key.ignore":"true","connection.url":"https://**.amazonaws.com","type.name":"kafka-connect","name":"elastic-search-sink-audit","errors.tolerance":"all","errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"fsp-dlq-audit-event"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq
```

and with EC2 IP address

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"elastic-search-sink-audit-distributed","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","tasks.max":"2","topics":"audit_event_distributed","key.ignore":"true","connection.url":"https://***.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com","type.name":"kafka-connect","name":"elastic-search-sink-audit-distributed","errors.tolerance":"all","errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"dlq_distributed"}}' http://10.67.39.217:8083/connectors | jq
```

After running this command after 1 minute i get below response

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   498    0    48  100   450      0      4  0:01:52  0:01:30  0:00:22    10
{
  "error_code": 500,
  "message": "Request timed out"
}
```

And then in i keep on getting this as well but this is just warning as i have enough replicas in my topic

```
NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
^C[2020-02-03 08:05:54,890] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 7185 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147476495 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
^C[2020-02-03 08:05:54,991] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 7186 on topic-partition connect-configs-0, retrying (2147476494 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:598)
```

When i described my topic

```
Topic:fsp-AUDIT_EVENT_DEMO      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: fsp-AUDIT_EVENT_DEMO     Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,6,2 Isr: 1,6,2
```

So i have enough replica for my topic .

**UPDATE**

Describe result of

```
Topic:connect-configs   PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-configs  Partition: 0    Leader: 6       Replicas: 6     Isr: 6


Topic:connect-status    PartitionCount:5        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 0    Leader: 6       Replicas: 6     Isr: 6
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 3    Leader: 4       Replicas: 4     Isr: 4
        Topic: connect-status   Partition: 4    Leader: 5       Replicas: 5     Isr: 5


Topic:connect-offsets   PartitionCount:25       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
```

Please help me resolving this .

Comment: Please provide logs after curl command running

Comment: Why are you posting to localhost?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander there is  no error returned to the caller or even logged at all

Comment: @cricket_007 i even tried with IP address of EC2 as well ..Second curl in question

Comment: `topic-partition connect-configs-0` doesn't have enough replicas. You're describing the wrong topic

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added for those topic as well which Kafka connect create by itself .I had added to my topic which i have created .Please have a look at my updated part of the question

Comment: Looks like you have 6 brokers. Why did you set replication factor to 1? (Also where is brokerId 3?)

Comment: By the way [using APT/YUM](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/index.html#production-environments) would be encouraged over tar.gz files

Comment: @cricket_007 so all three topic is created by kafka connect `connect-offsets connect-configs connect-status` .Do you suggest t change that ? Also where are you looking for broker id ?

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right ..The topic created by Kafka connect is not correct ..It does not crete with correct replication ..When i deleted all the three topics and created wiht 3 replica it worked fine

Comment: Cool. Feel free to provide answer below with the steps you followed @SUDAR

Comment: @cricket_007 i just followed your comment where you have mentioned `Why did you set replication factor to 1?` So i think you should really post this answer ..Again you were the savior for us ..

Comment: @Anupam Can you please elaborate more of how you made it work? You recreated these topics with all default values?  Can you please show the working version of you worker.properties and kafka topic describe output?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all three topic is created by kafka connect connect-offsets connect-configs connect-status

Indeed they are

```
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
```

> Do you suggest I change that ?

Not the names, but the replication factors, yes. 1 replica means if any one broker is down, then the topic is basically offline

> Also where are you looking for broker id ?

From columns 3-5 of the topic description

Comment: Should this set of parameters in worker.properties match which attribute(s) of the topic? number of brokers? ReplicationFactor?replicas? or min.insync.replicas?  Thanks.